# Can I lower AWS dependency size since I'm not using all of the services?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle, amazon-s3

We recently started using the AWS API for S3 and SES so we added this in our dependencies as required by the docs:

```
compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.48'
```

But our WAR file grew from a mere 66Mb to almost 150Mb.  Is there a way to cut down on the overhead with Amazon code as it's been flooding our Perm Gen and getting OOM.  I have temporarily increased our Perm Gen, but if I could remove the unnecessary code I might be able to lower our Perm Gen again.

Any official way to trim down the dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That pulls in the entire AWS SDK. If you only want to use specific services you can just include those specific SDK components.

For example, to include just the S3 and DynamoDB components of the SDK:

```
compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-s3', version: '1.11.48'
compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-dynamodb', version: '1.11.48'
```

You can see the different components by looking at the [project on GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java).

Answer (score 1):

The AWS SDK for Java is split up into packages based on their individual services.

The SDK docs suggest using Maven to import the individual packages.

Using Maven, add the SDK for Java's BOM to your `pom.xml` file as a dependency:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.22</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then you can specify the individual packages you want to import:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-project-maven.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using only S3 in your project I would recommend you to look at this.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-aws-s3-reactive

By using this way, The size of the JAR file has dramatically decreased

In my case when I used the entire AWS-SDK  it was around  250 MB -  after following the above approach it has decreased to 120 MB