# How can I reduced the maven Jar file size Currently 255 MB?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

How can I reduce the Maven Executable Jar file size. Currently its 255 MB. It is not allowing to deploy in Cloudformation.

I am doing the deployment via cloudformation --> Lambda and API Getway.

If I can reduce the file from 255 MB, Then my problem will be solved.

I have seen from the JAR file, This below 2 dependency are taking 195 MB.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.931</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-spring</artifactId>
            <version>[0.1,)</version>
```

What I should to reduce it ?

Complete Pom XML file are -

**Pom.xml -**

> 4.0.0
>
> org.springframework.boot
> spring-boot-starter-parent
> 2.1.1.RELEASE
>  
>
> com.myapp.app
> myapp-api
> 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
> myapp-api
> Demo project for Spring Boot
>
> <java.version>1.8</java.version>
>
>
>
> org.springframework.boot
> spring-boot-starter-actuator
>
>
> com.amazonaws.serverless
> aws-serverless-java-container-springboot2
> 1.5.2
>
>
> com.amazonaws
> aws-java-sdk
> 1.11.931
>
>
> org.springframework.boot
> spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb
>
>
> org.springframework.boot
> spring-boot-starter-security
>
>
> org.springframework.boot
> spring-boot-starter-web
>
>
> org.springframework.boot
> spring-boot-starter-mail
>
>
> org.springframework.boot
> spring-boot-devtools
> runtime
> true
>
>
> com.amazonaws.serverless
> aws-serverless-java-container-spring
> [0.1,)
>
>
> org.projectlombok
> lombok
> true
>
>
> org.springframework.boot
> spring-boot-starter-test
> test
>
> ```
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>net.authorize</groupId>
>           <artifactId>anet-java-sdk</artifactId>
>           <version>2.0.6</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
>           <scope>test</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
>           <version>0.9.1</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
>           <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
>           <version>2.9.2</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
>           <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
>           <version>2.9.2</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
>           <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
>           <version>2.9.2</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
>           <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
>           <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
>           <version>5.2</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
>           <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
>           <version>2.8.7</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
>           <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
>           <version>3.15</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
>           <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
>           <version>3.15</version>
>       </dependency>
>   </dependencies>
>
>   <build>
>       <plugins>
>           <plugin>
>               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>               <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
>               <version>3.1.0</version>
>               <configuration>
>                   <excludes>
>                       <exclude>*/.xml</exclude>
>                   </excludes>
>                   <archive>
>                       <compress>true</compress>
>                   </archive>
>               </configuration>
>           </plugin>
>           <plugin>
>               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>               <configuration>
>                   <excludes>
>                       <exclude>
>                           <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
>                           <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
>                       </exclude>
>                   </excludes>
>               </configuration>
>           </plugin>
>       </plugins>
>
>   </build>
>
> </project>
> ```

Comment: Is there any dependency are there which I need to add in Pom.xml ?

Comment: What dependencies do you already have in there? You need to check the content of the JAR, and what you really need and don't need. Adding dependencies in the pom.xml will just increase the file size, you need to remove them

Comment: @dunni - I added the pom.xml. All the dependency are useful.

Comment: And all those dependencies account for the file size? No other resources, like images or so, in the JAR?

Comment: @dunni - No. In the application properties I am doing the configuration. --

spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB
file.upload-dir=/home/pathofmyfile/myfile

Comment: Well, in the end we cannot guess what the problem is, we don't have the JAR file to inspect it. You have to open it and look what files take the size.

Comment: @dunni - Can you please let me know how to do that ? How I can inspect my Jar, and check what file take the size. I am new to this.

Comment: A JAR file is just a zip file, take any Unzip utility and extract it.

Comment: @dunni - Thanks a lot, Last question, Is there any specific folder or file, I should look at ?

Comment: No, again, we don't know what you have in that JAR. You have to look through all folders to find any large files or folders.

Comment: @dunni - I check, AWS SDK are taking 193 MB. Above SDK dependency I am using. which I have mentioned in the POM XML

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I lower AWS dependency size since I'm not using all of the services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41751382/can-i-lower-aws-dependency-size-since-im-not-using-all-of-the-services)

Answer (score 2):

This is issue is resolved, I am using AWS Dependency -

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.931</version>
        </dependency>
```

I don't need all the dependency, I need only S3 and Lambda. So Have remove this dependency. It decrease my Jar file. 255 MB to 50 MB.

Comment: If this solves your problem then you should mark your own answer as accepted!